# how to save state of a fragment on moving to other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Navigation Drawer have 4 fragment A,B,C,D
On moving from A to B want to save the list maintain in A.

onDestroyView is called but unable to pass arguments in that.

Comment: You could cache the Fragments yourself, or you could save the current state of the Fragment into a Database/KeyValuestone depending on the kind of information you need, to restore its state.

Comment: Are the four fragments on the same activity? Because if they are then changing fragment _should_ maintain the state of the first, as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Save instant of fragment by override onSaveInstanceState of fragment  and restore on onActivityCreated, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Save the fragment's state here 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
```

it will save each

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```